# Total number of duplicate rows in the database based on date

Tags: php, mysql

I have rows in my database. I want to show me the total quantity when the base_id row was duplicated on the same day
If the base_id row was repeated but the date was not for that day, show me separately
[mydatabase image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyRHZ.png)

For example, in the database image, if you see that we have 3 base_ids with the number 8, both of which have the same date, so these two should be displayed in one row with the sum of quantity And display that Base_id which is number 8 but has duplicate date in a separate row

my query

```
$records = $db->query("SELECT * FROM d_delivery_sargol LEFT OUTER JOIN d_base_list ON d_delivery_sargol.base_id=d_base_list.base_id");
```

I even used group based on date and base_id but this is wrong

Comment: Why grouping is wrong? This is actually what grouping is for. Try something like (not tested): `SELECT count(*) as dupes_count, SUM(quantity) as group_sum, base_id, \`date\` FROM  d_delivery_sargol GROUP BY base_id, \`date\`; `

Comment: @Jared This method works for me, thanks, but how can I join the base_list table?

Comment: Well.. just join it. Note that grouping will be performed for the whole result - both tables joined into one. Or you might use sub-queries like: `SELECT * FROM ( [here comes our grouped select]  ) grouped_table LEFT JOIN d_base_list ON grouped_table.base_id = .... `

Comment: @Jared please find an appropriate dupe to close with.

Comment: @Jared This didn't work for me. You can make a complete query based on the query you gave me above

Comment: @Jared SELECT count(*) as dupes_count, SUM(quantity) as group_sum, base_id, `date`  FROM  d_delivery_sargol LEFT OUTER JOIN d_base_list ON d_delivery_sargol.base_id=d_base_list.base_id  GROUP BY base_id, `date`

Comment: @Jared I run this query but I get an error

Comment: Try this `SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT count(*) as dupes_count, SUM(quantity) as group_sum, base_id, \`date\`
 FROM d_delivery_sargol 
  GROUP BY base_id, \`date\`
) grouped LEFT OUTER JOIN d_base_list ON grouped.base_id = d_base_list.base_id`